# Don't let the :after animation rule fire on page load

Tags: css, animation

I have the following code that does almost everything I need it to do.

```css
.mouse {
  margin-bottom:20px;
  padding:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
}
.mouse:after {
  content:"";
  height:2px;
  display:block;
  background:red;
  margin-top:5px;
  transform:translateX(100%);
  animation: hoverOut 1.5s ease 1;
}
.mouse:hover:after {
  animation: hoverIn 1.5s ease 1;
}
@keyframes hoverOut {
  0% {transform:translateX(0%);}
  100% {transform:translateX(100%);}
}
@keyframes hoverIn {
  0% {transform:translateX(-100%);}
  100% {transform:translateX(0%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse">watch the line below</div>
```

Basically when you mouse over the text, you see a line slide in from the left.  When you mouse out, you see the line slide out to the right.

My problem is if you go to your browser and press the refresh button to cause a page load, you'll see a line travel off to the right. I do not want this animation effect on page load.  Is there something I can do with just HTML and CSS ?  I do not want to introduce Javascript unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `animation` use a [**`transition`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) with the property [**`transform`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and a value of `scaleX`.

The "trick" here is to change [**`transform-origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) on the `hover` state.

Basically you do this:

```
.mouse:after {
  content: "";
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
}
.mouse:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.mouse {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
.mouse:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
}
.mouse:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse">watch the line below</div>
```

---

If you however want to use your `animation` as it is, you would need to use javascript.

You need to add a class once the user hovers your element, in this case `.running`.

The basics are this:

```
.mouse:after {
  content: "";
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: hoverOut 1.5s ease 1;
  animation-play-state: paused; /* Initial state of the animation, paused. */
  animation-delay: -1.5s; /* Get the first frame of the animation, this value has to be the total duration of the animation with a negative value */
}
.mouse.running:after {
  animation-play-state: running; /* When the class is added, the animation state is changed to running */
  animation-delay: 0s /* Set back to normal flow. */;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
document.querySelector(".mouse").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.classList.add("running");
});
```

```css
.mouse {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
.mouse:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: hoverOut 1.5s ease 1;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
}
.mouse.running:after {
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.mouse:hover:after {
  animation: hoverIn 1.5s ease 1;
}
@keyframes hoverOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
@keyframes hoverIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse">watch the line below</div>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Animations always run when the element becomes visible.(or the page loads)

For something like this you want to use a transition.  much more streamlined.
Here is your code using transition.

```css
.mouse {
  margin-bottom:20px;
  padding:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
}
.mouse:after {
  content:"";
  height:2px;
  display:block;
  background:red;
  margin-top:5px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
.mouse:hover:after {
  transform:translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mouse">watch the line below</div>
</body>
</html>
```